# iTextPDF 5.5 : How to add table at dynamic position on page vertically using Java?

Tags: java, itext

I want to add a table in PDF using iTextPDF 5.5 version at middle of the page or at some random place.
I have header on each page below which I have few lines of paragraph. Below which table should come.

```
HeaderFooterPageEvent event = new HeaderFooterPageEvent();
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        document.open(); //Adding Header on first page
        for(int i= 0 ; i< quotationDTOs.size(); i++) {
            if(i != 0)
                document.newPage();  // Adding header on new page
            WriteReference(quotationDTOs.get(i), document, writer);  //Adding para here
            WriteModels(quotationDTOs.get(i), document, writer); // Adding table here
        }

WriteModels(QuotationDTO quotationDTOTemp, Document document, PdfWriter writer)
{
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setTotalWidth(100);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Some text here"));
        cell.setFixedHeight(13);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setColspan(1);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        table.addCell(cell);
        document.add(table);QuotationDTO quotationDTOTemp, Document document, PdfWriter writer
}
```

Comment: If you *"have header on each page below which I have few lines of paragraph. Below which table should come"*, why don't you simply first add the *few lines of paragraph* to the document and then the table?

Comment: @mkl that is what I am doing. that was written to explain how page is designed. My issue is added table is overlapping header part and not coming after added paragraph.

Comment: Then your header is too large, or alternatively your top margin is too small. Simply increase the top margin of your document.